# How to notify client-side of an Instant-Message (IM) app of updates?

Tags: java, android, client-server, message, distributed-computing

I've been through different questions about this topic, however, none of them have cleared my doubts on the best approach notifying the client side of a server-client IM app.

**The Problem:**
The whole problem is how to notify the client application of updates. I've alread seen the following approaches:

1. **Clients keeps checking for updates**: From time to time, client app performs a check in the server to see if there are updates for that specific user;
   **Problem**: it is not performatic at all. Suppose you have one million users and each one of them checks for new updates every second. Serve would have to deal with one million requests per second. Wont work.
2. **Client app opens a socket**: The client app opens a socket and sends its address to the server. Server, by its turn, persists this information and connects to the socket whenever it needs to notify the client of some update.
   **Problem**: Often the client will be connected to a NAT, so, the IP it has access to is in a non-visible range. In order to send messages to this client, a port forwarding in the NAT would have to be configured, which can't be done.

*Despite of the technology, I think this approach will always be used, however, I have no idea how the problem described above can be solved.*

3. **Google Cloud Message (GCM)**: use the GCM service to notify the client of any update. **Problem**: It does't seems right to use a third server to handle the IM and it raises concerns about the scalability of the system. When the number of messages and users increases exponentially, it seems that the service will go down. Despite that, it seems that passing the information for two servers before delivering to the targets just adds bottlenecks in the process.
4. **A combination of 2 and 3**: uses GCM to reach the client when the last persist addres is no longer available.
   Problem: same as described in 2
5. **XMPP**: I've seen many answers indicating the use of XMPP for IM applications, however, XMPP is a protocol - as per what I've foun in the web. I don't see how it can solve the problem described in 2 for instance.

Given the options above, can someone indicate me what line should I try to go for? Which one of these approaches has the best chances of success?

Thank y'all in advanced.

Comment: GCM exists to do what your asking; it's engineered, supported and run by Google  - they are very good at what they do.

Comment: Hi Alex, even in a scenario with millions of users - and potential billions of messages - yet, GCM would be a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Cloud Messaging. Opposing to what you stated this service is built to scale to billions of users it will generally not introduce performance bottlenecks.

What you basically want to do is to use the messaging service to wake up devices. If you insist you can then still use your client server approach and thus your own protocol to have the client lookup new messages from the backend.

Comment: I'm sucessfully using GCM for my purpose. Thanks :)